# Excel SUMPRODUCT return 1 if value found in either of 2 named ranges

Tags: excel

I use the formula =SUMPRODUCT(--(A1=NamedRange)) frequently to mark a 1 if the value in A1 appears in NamedRange. What I need now is to mark a 1 if the value in A1 appears in either of 2 named ranges - let's say NamedRange1 and NamedRange2. I've tried a few permutations I can think of, but nothing's working.

Comment: try: `=SUMPRODUCT((A1=NamedRange)+(A1=NamedRange1))`

Comment: Returns "Value not available error"

Comment: Are the named ranges the same size?

Comment: In this instance I would use: `=--(COUNTIF(NamedRange1,A1)+COUNTIF(NamedRange2,A1)>0)`

Comment: No, they are not. Currently one has 24 and the other 11

Comment: or if the ranges are a single column or single row use MATCH: `=--(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,NamedRange1,0))+ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,NamedRange2,0))>0`

Comment: @ScottCraner for just a single named range, do you know the efficiency difference between COUNTIF() and SUMPRODUCT()?

Comment: Not much, but a little quicker, but the MATCH will beat both if a single column or single row.

Comment: try: `=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(--(NamedRange1=A1))+MAX(--(NamedRange2=A1)))`